# Turn cortana on for Dutch desktop

Tags: windows-10, language, cortana

I have Windows 10 home desktop and I will to use Cortana. The only problem is, my desktop is in Dutch and Cortana support only English. So can I turn on that on my desktop if I talk in English?

I have looked to the settings on the search bar but there stands this:

> Cortana does not support in the region and language you have selected.
>
> <sup>Translation from white text on image below.</sup>

[image: Cortana does not support in the region and language you have selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it! I have change the language of my desktop to English (United States).

[image: Setting window time & language, region & language]

[image: Cortana says: here are some of things I can do for you.]